# Nginx giving 400 Response on CSS files when disabling cache

Tags: css, caching, nginx, cache-control

I tried to implement the following directive in nginx to avoid caching of css files:

```
upstream turntown_stream {
    ip_hash;
    server turntown_host:9443;
}

location ~* \.(?:css)$ {
    root /data/nginx/html;
    expires 0;
}

location / {
    root /data/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
}

location /turntown/ {
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_pass https://turntown_stream/turntown/;
# Web sockets
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

However, whenever I try to apply the above directive, any css files that arrive on the web browser after a https://{DOMAIN}.com/turntown addrress is input, arrive with a 404 response.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`nginx` chooses a one `location` to [process a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Your new `location ~* \.(?:css)$` block takes precedence over the `location /turntown/` block when processing URIs that end with `.css`.

Therefore any URI that beings with `/turntown/` and ends with `.css` will be treated as a local file, and the request will no longer be sent upstream.

As an alternative, the `expires` directive can be used in conjunction with a `map`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) for details.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $expires {
    default          off;
    ~*\.(css)(\?|$)  0;
}
```

The `map` directive is placed within the `http` block.

```
expires $expires;
```

If the `expires` directive is placed in the `server` block, it will apply to all matching URIs irrespective of which `location` is used to process them.